# Custom graph in excel, x value is always 100% and y is a less than or greater than, showing that percent

Tags: excel, graph, vba

I have made a big macro generateing a graph to dynamic data. However, one of my graphs will show actual hours vs estimated. I am using a stacked 100% but the porblem is est vs  act can only be possible if est is < actual. I would like to set actual at 100% then have the second data series, estimated, to be either below or aboe that 100% to show 80% or 120% etc.

Thanks so much :)!

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Monthly").Delete

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
 If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "Calenders" And ws.Name <> "Front Page" And ws.Name <> "Arc" Then
        ws.Range("F129").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("BH65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next ws


 For Each ws In Worksheets
 If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "Calenders" And ws.Name <> "Front Page" And ws.Name <> "Arc" Then
        ws.Range("G128").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("BI65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next ws


  Range("BJ2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"
Range("BJ2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BJ2:BJ75"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("BJ2:BJ75").Select

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked100




ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Monthly"



ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Summary!$BH$2:$BH$53"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Estimated"""
```

Comment: show that part of the code you have problem with. we could than try to improve it. by `hours` you mean something like `time consumed` in hours?

Comment: I have an estimated time and actual time, what I have done is subtracted (Actual-est=data series (1)) and the est= data series two so it looks like a percent on the graph. Mathematicall it is correct, but it only works when the actual is > than the estimated.

Comment: @user2192609 can you attach an image of your chart? I'm not really understanding what you want it to look like, or what data you want to plot/omit.

Comment: I can't figure out how to post a picture!

Comment: you can add link to your picture if you can upload it somewhere in the internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a stacked bar is not the best type of chart for this problem.

Why not just use a simple column chart plotting the deviation (+/-), like this:

[image: column chart to display deviation from budget]

The research nerd in me suggests using stacked bar/column only for ordinal data type :) e.g., categories like "< 1 week", "1-2 weeks", "3+ weeks", etc.

**Alternatively** used a simple stacked bar/column (i.e., NOT the stacked 100%), which should allow you to display values like 120%.

Comment: I like the idea but I dont want to show - %. Maybe I jsut do not know enough about the whole graphing aspect of excel.